# Eloquent как создать запрос к двум таблицам?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Ребят, приветствую.
Знакомлюсь с Eloquent, и на пути такая задача.

Есть таблица с информацией о разделах `section`

```
|id|status|name    |
| 1|     0|section1|
| 2|     1|section2|
```

И есть таблица с записями `records`

```
|id|section|id_user|text |
| 1|      1|      1|text1|
| 2|      2|      1|text2|
| 3|      1|      1|text3|
```

Нужно получить записи, где раздел включен(`status = 1`)

```
$records = Records::where('id_user', Auth::id())->paginate(5);
```

Направьте в нужном направлении. Заранее премного благодарен.

Comment: Не совсем уверен в точности записи, но суть такова ``$records = DB::table('records')
                  ->join('section', 'id', '=', 'records.section_id')->where(['id_user','=', Auth::id()],['section.id','=','1'])->paginate(5);``

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить ([глобальный скоуп](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes)) на статус а потом просто искать через модель `Section::where('id_user', Auth::id())->with('records')->paginate(5);`
Где рекордс это связь таблиц записей и секций и все.

Comment: Вы что-то напутали с запросом, в Section нет id_user и будет не records, а record если уже и делать связь через belongsTo. И Вы не показали как делать через global scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете в моделе `Records` связь [hasOne](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one):

```
public function section () {
  return $this->hasOne(Section:class, 'id_user');
}
```

Теперь чтобы получить записи у которых section со статусом 1:

```
$records = Records::where('id_user', auth->id())->whereHas('section', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1);
})->paginate(5);
```

Вместо id_user наверное стоило бы написать user_id, в таком случае не пришлось бы указывать в `hasOne` второй параметр, laravel бы сам все понял.